# schemaTable.Rows(i).ToString order issues

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I found the code: `schemaTable.Rows(i)!COLUMN_NAME.ToString` online, but the columns are out of order. Is there a way to enforce row integrity?
I have columns that have numbers like `A1` and `A16` (not literally, just as examples) that, when listed, show up in order of `A1 A10 A11 ... A16 A2`.

UPDATE: 
TimG, this should explain what you're asking for, I hope.

```
Using db As New OleDb.OleDbConnect(constr)
      db.Open()
      Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(STATEMENT, db)
      Dim schemaTable As DataTable = db.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, table_name, Nothing})
      Try
         For i = 0 To SchemaTable.Rows.Count - 1
                 MsgBox(schemaTable.Rows(i)!COLUMN_NAME.ToString)
         next i
     catch e as exception
     end try
end using
```

This entire list returns out of order in the MsgBox (or any other display method). The columns display in the order in which the strings would if they were alphanumeric instead of by the numbers at the end (i.e. `A16` comes before `A2`) but the actual order is `A2 A3 A4 ... A16`. I'm not certain how to fix this issue outside of breaking down the strings themselves and looking for numerics in the string, but there must be a way to show the actual order in which they occur.

Comment: what do you mean by "row integrity"?  the order of rows and tables in the physical datastore is of little consequence.

Comment: I thought for ms access it was important. Am I wrong? I'm rather new to access databases and windows programming is a headache unto itself.

Comment: your SQL SELECT statements provide row order you want using the ORDER BY clause; it can also order the columns based on how they appear (ie `SELECT A1, A2, A3...A10, A11 FROM Foo ORDER BY...` vs `SELECT *...`.  For saving, the SQL Parameters map the data to the right column by name.  (and not my -1)

Comment: ORDER BY seems to only order by the data inside a row, not the name of the columns. I'm not entirely certain how to order the column names.

Comment: re-read my comment carefully: column order is specified by the order in which the column names appear in the SQL statement. ORDER By doesnt order "data inside a row" but the order of the rows in the dataset.

Comment: ...there is still the question of **why you care** about the column order in the dataset.  There are cases where that can be of concern, but your question provides no context.

Comment: I'm creating, writing to, reading from tables dynamically. I'm attempting to write a program to alter itself according to conditions to do alter, select, insert, and update statements with concern with unknown table names, column names, and values per field in a table. I'm attempting to generate all of these variables from calls to the tables and the columns to get names and the number of fields in a table.

Comment: currently my function looks like update_table(s() As Object, table_name As String, Prim_Key() As String)
Where s() is the objects to be written into the database

Comment: What makes you think that the columns are being returned in a different order (than you specified in your query)?  Sometimes, the debugger in VStudio shows stuff in alpha order for convenience, even though they are not really in that order. Please explain where you see this alpha-sorting occurring. VStudio, or a grid or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it appears that the `GetOleDbSchemaTable` approach (as outlined in the "Create Sample That Lists Columns in a Table" section of the Microsoft support document [here](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/309488/EN-US)) lists the columns in alphabetical order.

You might be happier with the results of using `SELECT *` to open an empty `OleDbDataReader` and then iterating through its fields:

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Using con As New OleDbConnection
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;"
            con.Open()
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM aTestTable WHERE False"
                Dim rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                For i = 0 To rdr.FieldCount - 1
                    Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetName(i))
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Will this list what's in the fields or the column names?

Comment: @NationWidePants It will list the column names. The DataReader doesn't actually contain any rows because of the `WHERE False` clause.

Comment: The statement you gave me seems to add a blank column at the end of the array (if rdr.GetName(i) was placed into an array). Not an issue, just wondered if you might know why. Is that a specific implementation of SQL for Access or a general return for the use of this statement? @Gord Thompson

Comment: @NationWidePants `rdr.GetName` is not Access-specific. I don't know why your array has a blank entry at the end, the code I posted does not return a blank entry (for me, anyway).